# How to inject coroutine dispatcher in Unit Test - using Koin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin-coroutines, koin

I am injecting my dispatcher, using Koin, into my classes

Extract of one class using Koin

```
class LogsWorker(
    val context: Context,
    workerParameters: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters), KoinComponent {


    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher by inject()
}
```

koinModule:

```
val appModule = module {
    factory { provideIoDispatcher() }
}

private fun provideIoDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
```

If I want to unit test my LogsWorker class, I need to inject a coroutineTestDispatcher.
How could I do that? I don't find any example anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override that bean definition in your testing, when you are loading you are starting koin and loading the modules.

You can do that with:
`factory(override = true) { provideYourTestingDispatcher }`

Read more about it [here](https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/modules#overriding-definition-or-module-before-310)

Although the above could work, I just find it more elegant to use constructor injection instead, for ex:

```
class LogsWorker(
    val context: Context,
    workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters)
```

Then you can just specify the definition for `LogsWorker` in koin, such as:

```
factory { (context: Context, workerParameters: WorkerParameters) -> LogsWorker(context, workerParameters, get()) }
```

And in testing, you can just simply pass in the testing dispatcher.
More info about this: https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-core/injection-parameters#defining-an-injected-parameter

**UPDATE:**
`override` is deprecated, you could use `KoinApplication.allowOverride(true)` instead

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to respond and edit your answer . I discovered some stuff about Koin I had no idea about - feels like I didn't have the right documentation.